# ScrollView with QtQuick.Controls 2.3 don't find library in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols, qt5.9

Today I've updated to Qt 5.9, I'm trying of use ScrollView, but this require this library: import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
When I import the library, and run, i receive this error:

> QtQuick.Controls 2.3 is not installed.

This is impossibile, because I've installed last release qt 5.9

I need to use [import QtQuick.Controls 2.1](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#details) to scroll content on android and ios.

Any solutions?

Comment: Why do you think `ScrollView` requires `QtQuick.Controls 2.3`?`ScrollView` works w/o problem using `import QtQuick.Controls 2.2`. Tested in QT 5.9/Windows 10/MinGW

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you link, is from the dev-branch of `Qt5.10` - this will probably come with `QtQuick.Controls 2.3`, so the import-statement there seems legit.

Your error-message is also correct, as `Qt5.9` ships with [`QtQuick.Controls 2.2`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html#versions)

The documentation link of yours however states, that `ScrollView` is available since `Qt5.9` - which is also backed by the documentation of this version, that can be found [**here**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html) - however then it is necessary to import the installed version `QtQuick.Controls 2.2`

If that does not work, I don't really see the superiority of the `ScrollView` over the [old-style attatching `ScrollBar`s to `Flickable`s](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#details).

Comment: I don't see QtQuick.Controls 2.2, I've only 2.0 and 2.1 with QT 5.9

Comment: Qt Creator's auto-completion for QML import versions is unfortunately not smart. Somebody just forgot to list the new version there. However, if you are using Qt 5.9, then you do have Qt Quick Controls 2.2 available.